# Error: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created

Tags: firebase, react-native

I have a React Native app that uses Firebase for various functions. It was working perfectly for 2 weeks until I got the below error. I haven't changed anything in the `App.js` so don't know why this issue would come across.

> [DEFAULT]: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).

Here is my config code placed in my `App.js`:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '<api-key>',
    authDomain: '<app-name>.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: '<project-id>',
    storageBucket: '<app-name>.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '<messaging-sender-id>',
    appId: '<app-id>'
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

This code only runs if I comment out the firebase code like the below in one of my components:

```
const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
console.log(currentUser);
```

Here is my `console.log(firebase.app())`;

[image]

Comment: The most logical explanation is that either this code doesn't get run, or it gets run after the call that raises the error. You might want to set a breakpoint or add some logging to see which of these it is.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The function that this block of code is in is the `componentDidMount`. I did a `console.log` after this config in the `componentDidMount` and it ran.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen What is quite weird is that in one of my components, if I comment out the code relating to firebase, this error goes away. I've updated my question.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**
You have all your configuration settings on your `componentDidMount`, might run several times while which leads to the problem you are having, I made the following changes and worked like a charm:

I create a `firebase.js` on the root, next to the `App.js`, that files look like this

```
import `firebase/app`
require(`firebase/auth`)

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: '<api-key>',
    authDomain: '<app-name>.firebaseapp.com',
    databaseURL: 'https://<app-name>.firebaseio.com',
    projectId: '<project-id>',
    storageBucket: '<app-name>.appspot.com',
    messagingSenderId: '<messaging-sender-id>',
    appId: '<app-id>'
};
if (!firebase.apps.length) {
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}

export auth = firebase.auth()
export default firebase
```

And your `App.js` then looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducers from './reducers';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import Router from './Router';
import { auth } from './firebase' // <----

class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
       this.checkAuth()
    }
    checkAuth = () {
       auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user, err) {
          console.log(user);
            if (user) {
              console.log(user);
               Actions.signUpVerify();
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
      });
    }

    render() {
        const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

You should not run the auth on your render method cause it might run potentially a lot of times.

Comment: Hello, I implemented this, but the app is still coming across as [DEFAULT]

Comment: `Firebase.apps` is coming as an empty array

Comment: then i need more information about your set up, it’s hard to tell where you error is

Comment: I've added my `console.log(firebase.app())` to the project. Hope this helps

Comment: is this public project? can i see a github or something? did u just create this map? you based all the question around a react lifecycle method, that is not good enough information, sorry

Comment: I also changed the config to run in `componentWillMount` and it didn't change anything

Comment: When I do get Firebase to run at times, I get the error "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." (auth/network-request-failed) when signing up a user

Comment: I was able to replicated, the first solution I gave u worked perfect, I will update the answer

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I have got this to work now, but when using Firebase authentication, I get the error: auth/network-request-failed

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In the react native app you don't have to configure firebase from javascript side.
In the IOS side, for example, add following lines within AppDelegate.m to initialize firebase manually.

At the top of the file import the Firebase module:

```
#import <Firebase.h>
```

Within the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, add the configure method:

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
      [FIRApp configure];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same issue in almost all my firebase projects but the solution to your problem is easy. You are trying to check an authenticated user as I see. The problem is that that method is asynchronous and the way you are implementing it isn't right. What you would do is use the firebase.onAuthstateChanged method and place it just after your firebase initialization area, something like this:

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '<api-key>',
  authDomain: '***',
  databaseURL: '***',
  projectId: '***',
  storageBucket: '***',
  messagingSenderId: '***',
  appId: '***',
  measurementId: 'G-HSYR9HXZF6',
});
// Enabling Offline Capability
firebase.firestore().settings({
  cacheSizeBytes: firebase.firestore.CACHE_SIZE_UNLIMITED,
});
firebase.firestore().enablePersistence();
// Listen to when a user logs in or logs out
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    const userDetails = {
      id: user.uid,
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email,
      provider: user.providerData[0].providerId,
    };
    console.log(userDetails)
  } else {
    console.log('No User Found')
  }
});
```