# Error setting up firebase with react possible unhandled promise rejection

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently creating a food ordering system and i am trying to set up firebase on a react-native project

The application lets me use authentication from firebase i can succesfully sign in and also register new users but it does not let me use firestore
i am trying to do a console log in the below code in my  to see if the firestore will run with the application

below is a list of the app.js/the screen where i am calling the collection from firestore

the error reads as so

[firebase error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O23M.png)
**//error reads on android emulator**

the build.gradle app level and the

//list of packages used on for react

package.json

```
"name": "projectFinal",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.3.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.3.4",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.3.4",
    "firebase": "^7.9.3",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.8.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.8.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

app.js


import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';

import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {createBottomTabNavigator, createTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'
import { HeaderButtons, HeaderButton, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import Home from './src/Screens/Home'
 //import MyAccount from './Screens/MyAccount';
 import Register from './src/Screens/Register'
 import Login from './src/Screens/Login';
 //import Menus from './Screens/Menus';
import LoadingScreen from './src/Screens/LoadingScreen';
// import Jitters from './Screens/Jitters';
// import Scullery from './Screens/Scullery';
// import Bunker from './Screens/TheBunker';
// import OrderDetails from './Screens/OrderDetails';
import ViewOrder from './src/Screens/ViewOrder';

import "firebase/firestore"
import firebase from "firebase"
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"

//this is where firebase is initializedd the google.services json is also in the relevant file

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIza<<redacted>>",
  authDomain: "<<redacted>>.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://<<redacted>>.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "<<redacted>>",
  storageBucket: "<<redacted>>.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "<<redacted>>",
  appId: "1:8<<redacted>>",
  measurementId: "G-T<<redacted>>"
};

// Instantiate a Firebase app.
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = firebaseApp.firestore()



 const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
         {
           Home: {
             screen: Home,
             navigationOptions: {
               TabBarIcon: ({ tintColor}) => <Ionicons name="ios-home" size={24} color={tintColor}/>
             }
          },
          // Menus: {
          //  screen: Menus,
          //   navigationOptions: {
          //     TabBarIcon: ({ tintColor}) => <Ionicons name="ios-chatbox" size={24} color={tintColor}/>
          //   }
          
           ViewOrder: {
           screen: ViewOrder,
           navigationOptions: {
            TabBarIcon: ({ tintColor}) => <Ionicons name="ios-add-circle" size={24} color={tintColor}/>
            },
         }
       },
       {
           tabBarOptions: {
             activeTintColor: "#161F3D",
             inactiveTintColor: "#E9446A",
             showLabel: true
      
      
           }
        
        }
       );
      
    
    
     const authStack = createStackNavigator(
       {
       Home: Home,
       Login: Login,
       Register: Register,
       // Menu: Menus,
      //  Jitters: Jitters,
      //  Scullery: Scullery,
      //  TheBunker: Bunker,
       // MyAccount: MyAccount,
      //  OrderDetails: OrderDetails,
       ViewOrder: ViewOrder
     });
    const App = createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
     export default createAppContainer(
      (
        createSwitchNavigator({
          
        Loading: LoadingScreen,
        App: TabNavigator,
        Auth: authStack
        },
        {
          initalRouteName: "Loading Page"
        }
      )
     )
     );

##Screen to call a collection of firestore##
//this is a console log to see if firestore will initialize 



import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {View, Text} from 'react-native'                                                                                                          
import firebase from "firebase"
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"



    
async function myFunction() {
   
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    
    let x = await firestore().collection("Users").doc("MmjyeGlhFPu0g6pK0GQ2").get();

   // console.log(x)

}



export default class ViewOrder extends React.Component {
    
      componentDidMount() { 
        myFunction(
        ) 
         }

render() {
    return(
            <View>
                <Text>Hello</Text>
            </View>
   
    )}


**//error reads on android emulator**  

as possible unhandled promise rejection (id:0) 
error: no firebase app ['default] has been created - call
firebase.initalize.app() getapp@http://10.0.2.2.8081/index.bundle
?platform
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems by the error, mainly for this below part:

> Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call firebase.initializeApp()

That you have not initialized your Firebase database. As informed in the documentation [firebase. app. App](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App), you need to call `firebase.initializeApp()` to create an app. Besides that, I would change your import to `import * as firebase from "firebase"`, so you are importing all packages needed for Firebase.

I have checked all these below posts from the Community and these possible solutions that I provided you, are just some options and alternatives that might solve your case.

I would recommend you take a look at them, so you can get more information and check further since there might be some other structure and environment configurations that can be affecting you and these cases can assist you with it.

- [No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/556)
- [Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created (Firestore)](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/258)
- [Error: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56639902/error-firebase-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created)
- [Error: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563140/error-no-firebase-app-default-has-been-created-call-firebase-app-initiali)

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks for getting back ive spent some time on this issue and cant get moving forward !! i have initalized firebase in the app.js 

import "firebase/firestore"
import * as firebase from "firebase"
import firestore from "@react-native-firebase/firestore"



const firebaseapp = firebase.initializeApp ({
  apiKey: ,
  authDomain: 
  databaseURL: ,
  projectId: ,
  storageBucket: ,
  messagingSenderId: ,
  appId: ,
  measurementId: 
});
const db = firebaseapp.firestore()

Comment: Hi @norb this should solve your case, which make this case indeed, very weird. Considering that, it might be an issue specific to your project, that would need to be checked by the Firebase team. I would recommend you to reach out to [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact). You should be able to contact directly [for free](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Comment: I have tried many fixes and followed all the stacks on the issue but nothing seems to work, i have forwarded this to firebase hopefully can find some sort of solution

Comment: Please, let me know if the Firebase team helped you and how you fixed and in case you think the answer helped you in anyway.

Comment: still no fix for this and firebase have told me to contact react 8-)

Comment: have now created a new react native application with only firebase dependencies, trying to add only firebase not firestore and receiving an error unhandled promise rejection id [o] cant find variable atob ?